# java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl in groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have the following groovy that has url validation:

```
            def url = new URL("https://" + domainIngress)
            def connection = url.openConnection()
            connection.connect()
        if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
            pipelineUtil.printm("//////////////////////          La URL del Dashboard es: ${url}          //////////////////////", "WARNING")
        } else {
            pipelineUtil.printm("//////////////////////          La URL del Dashboard está caída: ${url}          //////////////////////", "WARNING")
         }
```

and I get the following error in console:

```
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl
```

thank you if anyone knows how I can solve this problem.

I need to validate if the url that contains the variable ${domainIngress} responds with a status of 200 and if the status is different from 200 it tells me that this url is down but I always get the java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl problem.